# Is there a way in R to find all tweets containing a specific url?

Tags: r, twitter-api-v2

I have a dataset of tweets that I obtained from the Academic Twitter API by querying a list of terms.

```
search1 <- paste0("(rada'a ", 'OR radda OR radaa OR "al bayda" OR bayda OR AQAP)')

radaa.all <- get_all_tweets(search1,
                            "2013-12-02T00:00:00Z",
                            "2013-12-22T00:00:00Z",
                            bearer_token,
                            n = 100000,
                            data_path = "/Users/violetross/Desktop/Data Science/Evan's Project/radaa",
                            bind_tweets = FALSE)
```

I extracted every link shared within those tweets and expanded them to full URLs (from t.co shortened links). I would now like to use each of these URLs in a call to the API in order to find every tweet containing a given URL.

Essentially: I am starting with a list of full URLs and want a dataset for each URL containing all tweets sharing that URL.

I have tried using the get_all_tweets() function from the academictwitteR package in R, but for most urls it returns an empty data set (even though we know there is a minimum of one tweet containing each link).

```
for(i in 1:nrow(urls)){
  urlTweets[[i]] <- get_all_tweets(query = NULL,
                                   "2013-12-02T00:00:00Z",
                                   end_tweets = "2013-12-22T00:00:00Z",
                                   bearer_token,
                                   n = 10000,
                                   data_path = NULL,
                                   bind_tweets = TRUE,
                                   url = urls$fullURL[i])
}
```

Directly searching the API also returned empty datasets for most links.

Is there a better way to search for all tweets that contain a given a URL? Any ideas on why my searches return nothing for most URLs?